# shinyapps.io: data from API (read_lines())

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm new to shiny. My first project is to build an app that displays the NBA scores for a user selected date. It works perfectly when I run it on a local machine but does not work when I deploy to shinyapps.io.

I debugged it so far that I found what is not working. Apparently the app does not read the data from the NBA API.

Here is a code sample of what I'm doing:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(glue)

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Get NBA Scores"),

  # Select date
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      dateInput(inputId = "date",
                label = "Select Date")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      textOutput("boxscores")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  date <- reactiveValues()
  url <- reactiveValues()
  nba <- reactiveValues()

  # add leading zero to day
  observe(date$day <- ifelse(nchar(day(as.character(input$date))) == 1, paste0("0", day(as.character(input$date))), day(as.character(input$date))))

  # add leading zero to month
  observe(date$month <- ifelse(nchar(month(as.character(input$date))) == 1, paste0("0", month(as.character(input$date))), month(as.character(input$date))))

  # extract year
  observe(date$year <- year(as.character(input$date)))

  # create url
  observe(url$url1 <- glue("http://stats.nba.com/stats/scoreboard/?GameDate={date$month}/{date$day}/{date$year}&LeagueID=00&DayOffset=0"))

  #import data
  observe(nba$nba <- read_lines(url$url1))

  output$boxscores <- renderText({
    #plot raw data
    nba$nba
  })     
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When I just want to display the url using

```
output$boxscores <- renderText({
  #plot url
  url$url1
})
```

it works fine. But when I want to get the external data it does not show anything (not even an error).

Am i doing something wrong? Or is it not possible to read external data on shinyapps.io?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also posted this question in the RStudio community. shinyapps.io is hosted on AWS and it seems that NBA stats is blocking requests from AWS. See here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/shinyapps-io-data-from-api-read-lines/22936/2